# Order a summary result by a percentage?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate

my table 'product':

```
id:
1
2
3
4
```

my another table 'productSet'

```
id / specification
1  / 1
1  / n
1  / n
1  / n
1  / 1
2  / 1
2  / n
2  / n
3  / 1
3  / n
3  / n
3  / 1
3  / n
3  / n
3  / n
4  / 1
4  / n
4  / n
4  / 1
```

product.id = productSet.id

```
count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '1') = 5
count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '1' AND specification LIKE 'n') = 3
percent = (100-((3*100)/5)) = 40%

count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '2') = 3
count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '2' AND specification LIKE 'n') = 2
percent = (100-((2*100)/3)) = 33,33%

count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '3') = 7
count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '3' AND specification LIKE 'n') = 5
percent = (100-((5*100)/7)) = 28,57%

count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '4') = 4
count(productSet WHERE id LIKE '4' AND specification LIKE 'n') = 2
percent = (100-((2*100)/4)) = 50%
```

I NEED RESULT DESC

```
4 (50%)
1 (40%)
2 (33,33%)
3 (28,57)
```

Please help me with this command. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for explaining your question clearly, and providing the sample of the result you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy aggregate query to make.  Good use of `GROUP BY` with `SUM()` and `COUNT()` gives you a precise answer, and very efficiently.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95546c/8/0

```
SELECT id, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
       SUM(specification <> 'n') AS non_n_count,
       100.0 * SUM(specification <> 'n') / COUNT(*) AS percent
  FROM productSet
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

The trick here is to realize that the expression `specification <> 'n'` yields a value of either zero or one for each row in the table where there's a non-NULL value of `specification`. So summing up those values gives you a count of rows meeting the criterion.

`ORDER BY 4 DESC` orders the result set, descending, by its fourth column.

Comment: You're welcome. I've been where you are, trying to figure out complex stuff like SQL.